# How to re-integrate a branch in tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

I have finally successfully created and worked in a branch. I have commited my changes to the branch. Now I want to re-integrate the work in the branch into the main working trunk. How do I do that in tortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, if there are more changes committed  in trunk after you created the branch, then merge those changes into your branch (this is called rebase). Once that is done, you can [re-integrate branch](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) into trunk.

Otherwise after re-basing the branch from trunk you can do simple merge-revision option("Merge a range of revisions") as well.

If changes you made are not so big and there is very less changes into trunk also then you can also [create patch](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html) for you changes in branch and then apply them to trunk. But I would suggest to do the proper merge.

Comment: Im struggling to find a way to merge my trunks changes into the branch (which has an old version of the trunk). I.e update the branch.  I'm using tortoiseSVN, whos manual describes every type of merge except this one.  You call it re-base.  how does one do this?

Comment: Rebase is a concept. To apply this you need to choose one of the available merge options.